# How to use HTACCESS to block all visits to a specific subdomain, except from defined IP's

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**Scenario:** 
A single TYPO3 installation running multiple websites with multiple (sub)domains.

**What I'm trying to achieve:** 
 For one specific website I want to be able to block all traffic from the outside world, except visitors coming from the company's IP addresses.

**Pseudocode:** 
Block all visitors to this specific subdomain, except people coming from the following IP addresses.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?subdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(127\.0\.0\.1|192\.168\.|10\.|1\.2\.3\.4)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: "`${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}}`" - should be simply `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` in this example. (`ipmap` refers to a rewrite map, which hasn't been defined here, but also doesn't appear to be required).

Comment: You're right @MrWhite, I guess it was some bad copy/paste. Fixed it now and thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a simple auth block in your `htaccess` file in the `documentroot of the subdomain`. That's what it's for.

In Apache 2.2

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
#use your company's WAN IP addresses etc
allow from 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3
```

Or if you are using Apache 2.4, you can use this in your htaccess

```
#this is your company's WAN IP addresses etc
Require ip 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3
```